# How to reset external display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, monitor

So I was testing my laptop on my external scree and managed to cycle through the modes until I hit the one which displayed only on the external monitor.

This just output a green screen and nothing else. Now, whenever I connect the laptop I can't use the `fn+f3` button to swap between screen modes. It appears that it's stuck on this output.

Also to make things worse, the laptop seems to remember the setting, so now whenever I plugin the display all I ever get is a green screen. I've tried rebooting the laptop, but I  think the only way now is to reset the laptop somehow so it doesn't know that it's been connected to the external screen and I can use 'span' or 'mirror' mode instead of 'external only' mode, which clearly doesn't work.

**Update**
I've tried swapping to terminal using `CTRL+ALT+F1` but the external display goes to sleep.
I've tried using microDisplayPort -> HDMI -> DVI to the monitor with the same outcome.
It works fine on my TV using HDMI, but I haven't tried cycling the modes.
I got it working on the TV, and then moved the laptop to the monitor hoping it would work, but I had the same outcome.

I believe there is a setting somewhere in the system which is remembering the last used configuration for the specific monitor, and I would like to reset that, so that I can at least use my screen in span mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure how I got this to work, but I'll document the process in case anyone else has this same issue.

- Firstly I turned the laptop off
- Connect the display
- Turn on the laptop
- First time around this gave me a green screen again
- Press (in my case fnc+f1) to cycle the displays once
- This got me back to mirror mode

From mirror mode I could then use the display control panel to configure my displays into span, rather than just external.

Even though my Dell 2407WFP has a native resolution of 1920x1200 it seems that I can only output to it at 1680x1050. I think I might have a poor quality mDP -> DVI connector!

Answer (score 3):

Clearly you can't see what's happening on screen when this is the case, right? If so, this is a bit of a long shot, but try punching in CTRL+ALT+F1, then type in your username, enter, your password, enter, and then try

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --primary
```

Maybe that'll work. If not, your display probably isn't called LVDS1, in which case, disconnect from the external display and do:

```
xrandr -q
```

then replace 'LVDS1' above with whatever that command says your display is. It'll give you something along the lines of:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1920 x 1080
LVDS connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right) 304mm x 228mm
...
```

in which case, 'LVDS' is what you should use instead of 'LVDS1'.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry,this didn't work for me. when pressing `CTRL+ALT+F1` my monitor just goes into power saver mode.